# Hit enter to continue or skip function

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to write a program, and I've hit a bit of a bump. I was able to find how to do "hit enter to continue" easy, but now the function (void) that I have it in I also want to be able to skip right about where the first hit enter to continue pops up. Basically, I want to give the user the opportunity to either hit enter to continue with the rest of the function, or hit a button to skip the rest of the function. Here's an idea of what my code looks like currently:

```
void intro()
{
    int skip; // Not sure if I need this, was going to experiment

    cout << "Stuff being said " << endl;
    cout << "More stuff being said " << endl;
    cout << "Press 'enter' to continue...";
    cin.ignore(); // This is where I want the input to continue or skip.
```

So basically, I want to keep the hit enter to continue while also giving the user the opportunity to skip the function. Is this possible, or do I have to do something else entirely?

Comment: Do you know how to use `if` statements?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that, but wasn't sure how to go about it.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far. It's unclear what you want to decide whether or not a function is skipped. Is it based on user input? If they enter a specific word?

Comment: All based on user input. I was thinking that they could enter a specific key or any key other than enter, preferably the first if possible.

Comment: Ya, that's perfectly possible. Take input, and using an if statement check if their input is equal to a certain word/phrase. Your question as is is too broad for the site. I recommend trying to solve this, then when you run into a specific issue, post a new question asking how to overcome the problem. Right now, it sounds like you're asking for general advice/help, which is generally offtopic for the site.

Comment: I usually use `cin.ignore(1000000, '\n')` when I want to pause the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you should do, if your string is empty:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int main()
{
std::string temp;
std::cout << "Press Enter: ";
getline(std::cin, temp); // Taking input
if (temp.empty()) // if input is empty
    std::cout << "Enter Pressed"; // You can use 'break' or 'return' here
else
    std::cout << "Enter Not Pressed";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I can see this being useful beyond the little project I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution to your problem:  use **_getch()**.  It is a function inside of **conio.h** that pauses and waits for the user to press a key, then returns an **int** representing that character.  Here is an example of how you could use it in your code:

```
#include <conio.h> // put this somewhere up at the top of the file
void intro()
{
    cout << "Stuff being said " << endl;
    cout << "More stuff being said " << endl;
    cout << "Press 'enter' to continue or 'backspace' to skip...";
    int result = _getch(); // returns number equivalent of a character
    if (result == 8) // 8 is the number equivalent of backspace
        return;
    ...
    code
    ...
}
```

*(technically any key besides backspace would continue)*

You can use this [table](http://www.asciitable.com/) as a basic reference to which characters belong to which numbers.